# TFS Check in policy -Disable permissions

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have a custom check-in policy in TFS. I want this policy to be disabled only by Admins and not by Developers.Developers should not be allowed to remove the policy on their machines. How do I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You must have the **Edit project-level information** permission set to **Allow** if you want to Enable or Disable Check-In Policies.

You can **deny** Edit project-level information for Developers, so they won't be able to change the check-in policy.